# Basic Javascript Question - What trigger to use?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this script to auto populate my date field on a form:

```
function clearText(thefield){
if (thefield.defaultValue==thefield.value)
thefield.value = ""
} 

function zp(n){
return n<10?("0"+n):n;
}
function insertDate(t,format){
var now=new Date();
var DD=zp(now.getDate());
var MM=zp(now.getMonth()+1);
var YYYY=now.getFullYear();
var YY=zp(now.getFullYear()%100);
format=format.replace(/DD/,DD);
format=format.replace(/MM/,MM);
format=format.replace(/YYYY/,YYYY);
format=format.replace(/YY/,YY);
t.value=format;
}
```

Then using this to trigger the event:

```
onfocus="insertDate(this,'DD/MM/YYYY')"
```

My question (which is probably a basic one!) is what should I use to auto populate the field when the page loads rather than when I click on the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `onload` then, there is no need to wait until all page requisite complete loading. Put you script which invokes `insertDate` right after desired `<input>`. eg:

```
<form name="theform">
<input type="text" name="thefield" value="fallback date from server-side">
<script type="text/javascript">
// able to reference field now
insertDate(document.theform.thefield,'DD/MM/YYYY');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function () {
//your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate it when the page loads, you can use the onload handler on `<body>`, like so: `<body onload="foo ();">`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are auto populating the field, I believe it is *less confusing* to the user if it is populated when then page loads rather than when the field gets the focus.